# Javascript color scale from 0% to 100%, rendering it from any color to any color on progress bar

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I have a progress bar and I would like it to render colors from red for 0% to green for 100%. 
I am using the js snippet from here https://gist.github.com/mlocati/7210513 which works nicely, but I would like to specify the exact colors to for 0% and 100%.

red color that I want: rgb(239,**83**,80) for 0% (#ef5350)
green color that I want: rgb(**54**,161,14) for 100% (#36a10e)

Red color I have at the moment: rgb(239,**0**,80), (#ef0050)
green color I have at the moment:  rgb(**0**,161,14). (#00a10e)

How do I get 83 and 54?

```js
function perc2color() {

  var progressBar = $('#progress-bar');
  var value = $(progressBar).data('value');

  var r = 0;
  var g = 0;
  var b = 0;
  if (value < 50) {
    r = 239;
    g = Math.round(5.1 * value);
    b = 80;
  } else {
    r = Math.round(510 - 5.10 * value);
    g = 161;
    b = 14;
  }
  var h = r * 0x10000 + g * 0x100 + b * 0x1;
  window.alert('#' + ('000000' + h.toString(16)).slice(-6))
  progressBar.css({
    backgroundColor: '#' + ('000000' + h.toString(16)).slice(-6),
    width: value + '%'
  });
}
perc2color();
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  height: 100%;
}

.progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" id="progress-bar" data-value="100"></div>
</div>
<!-- to see the difference just change the number in data-value to anything between 0-100 -->
```

Comment: What is wrong here? I did not understand

Comment: result of this gives rgb(239, 0, 80) for 0% and rgb(0, 161, 14), but I want rgb(239, 83, 80) for 0% and rgb(54, 161, 14) for 100%. i rework the snippet to show the color #.

Comment: Why does not store colors in array. Like http://jsfiddle.net/1k287coy/

Comment: so now the color at 100% is #00a10e, but I want #36a10e. is array going to give me different color for every % so 100 colors?

Answer (score 0):

The formula is quite simple:

```
 Math.round(start + (end - start) * value / 100);
```

That way it will be `start` for `0` and `end` for `100`.